# How to post a form to self?

Tags: php

I have a page which is accessible via a url - something like this http://websitename/index.php?q=pagename. On this page, I have a form that I would like to submit to the same page so that I could do some post processing. I have tried the following things but couldn't get it to work -

```
<form name="formname" action="pagename.php" method="post">
<form name="formname" action="" method="post">
<form name="formname" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

In other words, I would like to submit the form to pagename.php file (where the form resides). The page (pagename.php) is not directly accessible. How do I get this done? I will greatly appreciate any help on this one. Thanks.

Comment: How about action="" ?

Comment: if it's not directly accessible - how will the browser access/submit the data to it?

Comment: @frz3993, I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks

Comment: @Oleg Dubas, it is accessible via a url - http://websitename/index.php?q=pagename.

Comment: The page resides in websitename/foldername/pagename.php. On the website it can be accessed like this - http://websitename/index.php?q=pagename. So my question is - is it possible to submit the form to  /index.php?q=pagename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In HTML5 you can just do `<form>` and its set to self.

```
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">
```

*OR*

```
<form name="formname" id="mainForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
```

*OR*

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
```

The point is your `$_SERVER` variable contains all the information you would require to generate that specific page's URL. If you have decided not to go with the HTML5 way, then one of these options should work. Otherwise you're missing something else not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will solve your problem

```
<form name="formname" action="#" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <form method="post">/*your stuff here*/</form>
```

and you should add a submit button with attribute "name=submit" so the form could be submitted also track if its have been posted with php then do your actions like below

```
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ /* your code */}
```